# cannot find the symbol class NativeContentProvider

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-contacts, phone-number

When i compiled the program it's showing error 
cannot find the class NativeContentProvider

The given below is the code i was trying to use but not working

```
    private void displayContacts() {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void clickFunction(View view){
        displayContacts();
    }
```

Where clickFunction is the onClick method of the button

Comment: what is name of the class you put this code ?

Comment: Post your logcat please.

Comment: looks like you've copied some code from the internet that contains a class name reference, just replace `NativeContentProvider.this` with `this`, and see if that works

Comment: I'm using that code in MainActivity class directly to access all the contacts.

Comment: @ARDANISH You should pass `CONTEXT`

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here `NativeContentProvider.this` this should be activity or context !!

Comment: what's name of your Class in which you are using this. can you show me full class code.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Syntax of [**`Toast`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#java) .

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

Try with

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Or**

```
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: tried both one but when i clicked the button it shows app has stopped. Open it again

Comment: error: cannot find symbol class NativeContentProvider, execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.